# Can't append rows from dynamic table but can append whole table

Tags: jquery

I'm clearly not seeing something obvious, but why can't I append part of a dynamically generated table (first 2 rows in this case) to a div, but I CAN append the whole table.

```
<div id="divarea"></div>

    var table = '<table id="abc">';
    for (var i=0; i<15; i++) {
  table += '<tr>';
  table += '<td>one</td>';
  table += '<td>two</td>';
  table += '<td>three</td>';
  table += '<td>four</td>';
  table += '<td>five</td>';
  table += '<td>six</td>';
  table += '<td>seven</td>';
  table += '<td>eight</td>';
  table += '</tr>';
}
table += '</table>';

// var limitTable = $('#abc tr:lt(2)'); 
// $('#output').append(limitTable);          Doesn't work 

$('#output').append(table); // This works
```

EDIT: table id= "abc" added

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shindig/47e9c264/30/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use correct selector. You can use:

```
var limitTable = $("tr:lt('2')", table);
```

```js
var table = '<table id = "abc">';
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  table += '<tr>';
  table += '<td>one</td>';
  table += '<td>two</td>';
  table += '<td>three</td>';
  table += '<td>four</td>';
  table += '<td>five</td>';
  table += '<td>six</td>';
  table += '<td>seven</td>';
  table += '<td>eight</td>';
  table += '</tr>';
}
table += '</table>';
//the second parameter provides the context
//in which to search the element matched by the first selector
var limitTable = $("tr:lt('2')", table);
$('#output').append(limitTable);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Also is better to append table elements into table and not in a div.

Comment: Thanks you! I did notice that using $('#abc tr:lt(2)') does work for a table that is hard coded onto the page. But not in this case. I think that was confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

use **[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** in jquery

```
var limitTable =  $(table).find("tr:lt(2)");
 $('#output').append(limitTable);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/47e9c264/33/)**

Comment: @MatthewMoon Both are same,  *$("tr:lt('2')", table);*,this logic comes under find() , you have to see jquery source code